# Open webapp from command line (Jailbreak IOS 9)

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I am using a couple of old ipads with IOS 9.3.5 as a display at home for my domotica. Using sblaunch I can unlock the ipad and open an url when there is movement. However I would like to have my webpage show fullscreen. I added the required fullscreen tags and added the website as a button on the home screen called 'Main123'. When I click this with my finger it opens my statusdisplay fullscreen. Is there a way to do this using the open command? Or any other way this  homemade homescreen button?